# isolated storage question

Tags: c#

How do i store an object (of class) into isolated storage?

thanks

Comment: Awww, that's gonna be one lonely object.

Comment: ... and only 57 upvotes!

Comment: @Ed Swangren: it's the naughty corner for objects

Comment: @John c'mon this guy probably has five kids to feed!  Help him keep his job!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing and reading an object (XML serialized/deserialized) to/from isolated storage:

```
namespace IsolatedStorageSerialization
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            object thisIsAnObject = new object();

            SerializeToIsolatedStorage(thisIsAnObject, "object.xml");

            object anotherObject = DeserializeFromIsolatedStorage<object>("object.xml");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void SerializeToIsolatedStorage<T>(T obj, string filename)
        {
            if ((obj == null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            {
                return;
            }

            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly())
            using (var stream = store.CreateFile(filename))
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
            {
                new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()).Serialize(writer, obj);
            }
        }

        private static T DeserializeFromIsolatedStorage<T>(string filename)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly())
            using (var stream = store.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open))
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
            {
                return (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading/writing to isolated storage is no different than reading/writing to regular file system. So if you wish to store your object into isolated storage, you need to serialize it - you have quite a few serialization options in .NET including runtime serialization, xml serialization, DataContract (WCF) serialization, JSON serialization etc. Use one that suites you and don't forget about versioning your objects. Object serialization will give you bytes or characters stream that you can persist in isolated storage.

To get started with isolated storage, you can refer below links:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IsolatedStorage.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=VS.100).aspx